# Prevent Realm from overwriting a property in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I have my Realm Object like this:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Employee: Object {

dynamic var empID : Int = 0
dynamic var empName : String = ""
dynamic var isActive : Bool = false

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "empID"
 }
override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["isActive"]
 }
}
```

The empID and empName are set from JSON from my server. But the isActive is set when user clicks a button in my apps. Every time I click a button I can change the status isActive to be true or false, but after I reload the apps, the status is reset back to false. How can I save the isActive status permanently even if the apps reload again?

Comment: So you just want Realm to keep track of the `isActive` flag? Just remove it from `ignoredProperties`.

Comment: Need more information, because the simple solution is to just add `isActive` as a field to your database. Explain why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: so what that doesnt work is for example i change isActive to true. And while I'm not closing the apps the status still true. But when i try to open the apps again after a while for example, i fetch the data from the API and the isActive is back to false.

Comment: If you want the value of `isActive` to persist across sessions, then you can't make Realm ignore it. Connor and BaseZen are right. If you have an `isActive` key in the JSON you get from your server that you want to _ignore_, just remove the key from that dictionary before passing it to Realm and the `create`/`init` operation will leave that property alone.